# Обнулить offset в RectTransform, расположив anchors по углам rect

Tags: c#, unity3d, transform

> Кратко: как провести линию из нижнего левого в правый верхний угол экрана?

Если я сделаю:

```
offsetMin = Vector2.zero;
offsetMax = Vector2.zero
```

То прямоугольник встанет точно по якорям, будто я вручную в инспекторе обнулил параметры `Left`, `Top`, `Bottom`, `Right`.  А я хочу с точностью **да наоборот**.

Нажимаешь на кнопку контекстного меню — якоря встают по углам прямоугольника.

Мой ход мыслей таков:

1. `anchorMin` и `anchorMax` - это позиции нижнего левого и верхнего правого якорей соответственно **от 0 до 1**.
2. `Screen.width` и `Screen.height` - размеры экрана
3. Чтобы получить `anchorMin` и `anchorMax` можно позиции нижнего левого и верхнего правого якорей разделить на размеры экрана.

Для проверки я написал такой код:

```
[MenuItem("CONTEXT/RectTransform/Nullify")]
static void Nullify (MenuCommand command)
{
    RectTransform RT = (RectTransform)command.context; // Получаем RectTransform

    Vector2 RectMin = new Vector2(RT.position.x - RT.rect.size.x / 2,
                                  RT.position.y - RT.rect.size.y / 2); // Минимальный угол прямоугольника
    Vector2 RectMax = new Vector2(RT.position.x + RT.rect.size.x / 2,
                                  RT.position.y + RT.rect.size.y / 2); // Максимальный угол прямоугольника

    Debug.DrawLine(RectMin, RectMax, Color.red, 10); // Линия между углами прямоугольника
    Debug.DrawLine(Vector2.zero, new Vector2(Screen.width, Screen.height), Color.green, 10); // Линия между углами экрана
}
```

И вот тут появляется интересность: первый луч проводится точно между углами прямоугольника, а вот второй луч выходит из нижнего левого угла экрана и заканчивается совершенно не в правом верхнем, а где-то выше и левее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я думаю, что мой подход верен, но он ломается из-за того, что я не могу нормально получить координаты верхнего правого угла экрана. Хотя по факту это должно быть `Screen.width, Screen.height`, нарисованная линия показывает, что это не так.

В итоге ответом на мой вопрос будет хотя бы **одно** из:

- Координаты верхнего правого угла экрана
- Как провести линию между углами экрана
- Как реализовать это: "Нажимаешь на кнопку контекстного меню — якоря встают по углам прямоугольника" (это уж прям совсем глобальный вопрос)

Comment: По факту это RectTransform.deltaSize родителя(canvas). Debag.DrawLine вообще в мировых координатах, я не уверен, что он тут поможет.

Comment: В смысле, как реализовать кнопку? Ты же написал пункт для контекстного меню компонента.

Comment: @Yaroslav Кнопку контекстного меню :)

Comment: АААааа... вот в чём подвоха! `Transform` же не `MonoBehaviour`, контекст ему так не добавишь. Ненавижу его за это, и корутину с него не запустишь, бесит.

Comment: @Yaroslavl Что вы имеете в виду? Тот код, который я прикрепил прекрасно работает! Он создает кнопку в меню компонента Transform (открывается при нажатии на три точки в правом верхнем углу компонента). Самая нижняя строчка — Nullify. Она кликабельна, и работает: отрисовываются две линии. Вот только я не понимаю, как теперь реализовать то, что мне нужно. Именно сам код. Мой способ не сработал